# Three.js image quality blured

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, three.js

I have made a cube with textures with `three.js`. When I add a texture, the quality is not good. It's light blurry and I don't know how fix it.

Example:

**Original image**

[image]

**Image in Three.js (blurry)**

[image]

---

You can see better bellow: (The blue and gold in the head are not the same)

**Original Image**

[image]

**Image in Three.js (blurry)**

[image]

I have tried a lot of solutions:

```
texture.anisotropy =  16;
```

-

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1)
```

-

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { 
   canvas: theCanvas,
   antialias: true,
   preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
   alpha:true
} );
```

I have tried to change the light too but it was never working. Is it possible to change the image quality directly in `three.js`?

Answer (score 2):

in 2020

```
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load();
    texture.generateMipmaps = false;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: I have a very similar issue and these suggestions didn't help me :/ If you have a minute, could you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117578/threejs-how-to-improve-texture-image-resolution

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
texture.generateMipmaps = false;
```

Comment: not work but now an brilliant overlay appear. How disable it?

Comment: I use a animate function

Answer (score 0):

Set the texture minFilter property.
THREE.js default is none.

```
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load();
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

Comment: This is incorrect and possibly misleading default is [THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.minFilter).

Comment: What's your three version?

Comment: dev or latest (r104), both default to THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter. [reference](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/textures/Texture.js)