# ThreeJS - How to Improve Texture Image Resolution

Tags: three.js

I have the following image that I'm trying to set as my Three JS `scene.background`:

[image]

If I do:

```
scene.background = backgroundLoader.load(trial.imageURL);
```

I get a low resolution image:

[image]

Other posts (e.g. [Three.js image quality blured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907919/three-js-image-quality-blured)) have suggested setting the `minFilter` and `magFilter`, but I find both of these offer little improvement. When I do:

```
          scene.background = backgroundLoader.load(trial.imageURL, function (texture) {
              texture.generateMipmaps = false;
              texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
              texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
              texture.needsUpdate = true;
          });
```

I get the following image:

[image]

How to I make the `scene.background` texture have its original resolution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting image as three.js scene background makes it blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272791/setting-image-as-three-js-scene-background-makes-it-blurry)

Comment: I tried those solutions too. I just didn't also link that post since I linked the other one. They aren't working for me.